# SQL Server datasets

Tags: sql, sql-server, dataset, data-analysis

I would like to know if there are any SQL Server ready datasets which one can use. I know there's AdventureWorks (which i'm already using), but i would like to know if there are more.

I also open for paid solutions.

Thank you,

Vítor Barreto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kimberly "The Queen of Indexing" Tripp of SQL Skills fame has a few very good, pretty large sample downloads available for free:

https://www.sqlskills.com/sql-server-resources/sql-server-demos/

And if you want a really *enourmous* data set - you can download the whole (anonymised) Stackexchange dump from here:

https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2011/10/3/places-to-download-sample-data.html